# How to use route for html file already served as static

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I use passport.js to authenticate user after he enters login page. To keep user logged in when he returns to home page i'm going to use something like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
   if(req.user){
   // connect to database ....
} else{
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
   }
});
```

Note that index.html file is inside "public" folder. Recently i realized that having a code like above, node.js doesn't use app.get('/'....) route but it serves index.html directly. So i'm unable to check if req.user exists. Any suggestion?

Comment: it's long to teach You node and passport. just watch tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGTvjcgWt00

Comment: I think providing a small answer is better than proposing to watch a video 1.33h...

Comment: ok. 1. I've to give example on how to use middlewares, 2. I've to show how to create local strategy and then use it's middleware, 3. I've to fix Your code. Total: You'll just copy paste it and will learn nothing.  1.3 hr video is an example, search for short one. You people become too lazy to learn. You even don't want to read official manual: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/   Why others must do Your job for You?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1ktxiqyiLA&list=PL1Fsv-9XT-Xd1Cpa8P7FGzgbJZ_F_mmt0   Traversy Media explains better

Comment: If You want to alway serve html file. You just have to move file response out of `else` part. `app.get('/', (req, res) => { if (req.uses) {/*do something*/} res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); });`  it's too simple too basic to understand.

Comment: node doesn't see app.get at all. Is it too hard to read question carefully;

Comment: it means You use something in front of express app. Nginx? Apache? how You run Your app? where's details?

Comment: nothing...pure node

Answer (score 0):

As You might understand `express.static` handles index.html before Your router.

But You cannot avoid express.static also (otherwise You have to use nginx or write own static file output).

So You've to **re-think Your folder structure** or have to develop 2 separate apps: api (backend) and frontend (that will request to api for data)

In context of Your question I wrote an example app where I organize assets, html files and app routes:

1) Have such folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

2) and example `app.js` :

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// attaching renderer
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile); // ejs renderer will render .html files as ejs files
app.set('view engine', 'html');          // views has .html extension
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public'); // views live in public folder

// attaching common middlewares
app.use('/assets', express.static('public/assets')); // our static assets will live in public/assets folder
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());


// implement and attach passport auth somewhere (:
// remove it after passport has been attached:
const authorizeUser = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user = {id: 1, username: 'test'};
  next();
};

app.get('/', authorizeUser, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {user: req.user});  // render get index.html from views folder (see above)
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('App listening');
});
```

p.s. download example app [from here](http://anarjafarov.me/example-express-app.zip) (don't forget to call `npm i` inside extracted folder (;  )

p.s. implement passport.js Yourself